# Is partial data read possible from a pipe due to delay in writing?

Tags: linux, pipe, posix, ipc, embedded-linux

I have a situation where one process is writing 512 bytes of data to a pipe every 100ms, and another process is continuously reading from the same pipe. It took three read operation to read complete 512 bytes of data from pipe. The first read operation returns only a portion of the data (e.g. 100 bytes), and the next read returns zero bytes without any error set and the last read operation reads the remaining data left in the pipe (e.g. 412 bytes).

I assume that the write operation is atomic as the 512 bytes is lesser than PIPE_BUF bytes. If so, is it possible for a read operation to return partial data, especially it took three reads for reading 512 bytes and the second read returned zero bytes.

```
// Create the named pipe
if (mkfifo("/tmp/my_pipe", 0666) == -1) {
    perror("mkfifo");
    return 1;
}

 // Open the named pipe for reading and writing with non- 
 // blocking behavior
if ((fd = open("/tmp/my_pipe", O_RDWR | O_NONBLOCK)) == -1) {
    perror("open");
    return 1;
}


// Open the named pipe for reading with non-blocking behavior
if ((fd = open("/tmp/my_pipe", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) == -1) {
    perror("open");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: On Linux, it depends on whether you opened the pipe in packet mode.  Traditionally, a pipe carries a stream of bytes, and there's no correlation between the number of 'sends' and the number of 'receives'.  [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html).

Comment: @undefinedsymbol Thanks for the response. Added the code section for clarification. The pipe is opened with default mode and non blocking is set.

Comment: You did not specify O_DIRECT on open, therefore it looks like the fifo is created in byte-stream mode.  See [man 2 pipe](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) - which apparently applies to fifos as well.

Comment: Hello, I'm looking for a reference or example implementation that shows how to use O_DIRECT to read and write to a named pipe in packet mode instead of byte mode. I know that O_DIRECT can be used to bypass the kernel buffer cache and read or write directly to the disk, but I'm not sure how to ensure that the data is transmitted in packets with fixed boundaries. Do you have any suggestions or can you point me towards any relevant resources?

Comment: I think it is better to focus on the original question. If the read can see partial data in the pipe even if the write is atomic up to PIPE_BUF, then please provide some reference to the answer from POSIX or man page. Then let us close the original query.

Comment: I provided that reference in my first comment, but I have expanded it into an answer.

Comment: Like you, I'm surprised that _atomic_ writes to a FIFO buffer would not be read in one "scoop."  Can you reproduce this behavior with a trivial writer and reader program and the `mkfifo` utility?

Comment: This issue is generally rare and difficult to reproduce consistently. My understanding is that it can occur when data is being written to the pipe concurrently with another process attempting to read from it. I would like to get the insight from others before attempting to modify the code

Answer (score 0):

The man page for pipe (i.e., `man 7 pipe`) says

> The communication channel provided by a pipe is a byte stream: there
> is no concept of message boundaries.

This terse statement implies that reads can see what you call 'partial data' from the pipe; rather that there is no such thing as partial data, because it's a *byte stream*.

For what it's worth, TCP has the same feature.