# Is Partial Data Read Possible from a Pipe During Simultaneous Write?

Tags: linux, pipe, ipc, embedded-linux

In a pipe communication channel, if a process writes less than PIPE_BUF bytes to a pipe, can the read operation from another process reading from the same pipe simultaneously see only a part of the written data, or is the write operation atomic even in this case?

Can someone please provide a reference to the relevant documentation or standards?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is partial data read possible from a pipe due to delay in writing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75504171/is-partial-data-read-possible-from-a-pipe-due-to-delay-in-writing)